# Insert dictionary(JSON) as is in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a usecase where I need to convert the existing columns of a dataframe into JSON and store in only on one column.

So far I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df=pd.DataFrame([{'a':'sjdfb','b':'jsfubs'},{'a':'ouhbsdv','b':'cm osdn'}]) #Random data
jsonresult1=df.to_json(orient='records')
# '[{"a":"sjdfb","b":"jsfubs"},{"a":"ouhbsdv","b":"cm osdn"}]'
```

But I want the data to be just string representation of the dictionary and not the list. So I tried this:

```
>>>jsonresult2=df.to_dict(orient='records')
>>>jsonresult2
# [{'a': 'sjdfb', 'b': 'jsfubs'}, {'a': 'ouhbsdv', 'b': 'cm osdn'}]
```

This is what I wanted the data to look like but when I try to make this a dataframe the dataframe again is in the format of 2 columns [a,b]. The string representation of these dictionary objects will insert into the dataframe the column data in the required format.

```
>>>for i in range(len(jsonresult2)):
...    jsonresult3.append(str(jsonresult2[i]))
...
>>> jsonresult3
["{'a': 'sjdfb', 'b': 'jsfubs'}", "{'a': 'ouhbsdv', 'b': 'cm osdn'}"]
```

This is exactly what I wanted. And when I push this to a dataframe I get:

```
 >>> df1
                              0
 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 0  |   {'a': 'sjdfb', 'b': 'jsfubs'}
 1  |{'a': 'ouhbsdv', 'b': 'cm osdn'}
```

But I feel this is a very inefficient way. How do I make it look and work in an optimized way? My data can exceed 10M rows. And this is taking too long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd first convert to a dictionary... Make into a series... then apply `pd.json.dumps`

```
pd.Series(df.to_dict('records'), df.index).apply(pd.json.dumps)

0       {"a":"sjdfb","b":"jsfubs"}
1    {"a":"ouhbsdv","b":"cm osdn"}
dtype: object
```

Or shorter code

```
df.apply(pd.json.dumps, 1)

0       {"a":"sjdfb","b":"jsfubs"}
1    {"a":"ouhbsdv","b":"cm osdn"}
dtype: object
```

We can improve performance by constructing the strings ourselves

```
v = df.values.tolist()
c = df.columns.values.tolist()

pd.Series([str(dict(zip(c, row))) for row in v], df.index)

0       {'a': 'sjdfb', 'b': 'jsfubs'}
1    {'a': 'ouhbsdv', 'b': 'cm osdn'}
dtype: object
```

---

If memory is an issue, I'd save `df` to a csv and read it in line by line, constructing a new series or dataframe along the way.

```
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

This is slower, but get's around some of the memory issues.

```
s = pd.Series()
with open('test.csv') as f:
    c = f.readline().strip().split(',')[1:]
    for row in f:
        row = row.strip().split(',')
        s.set_value(row[0], str(dict(zip(c, row[1:]))))
```

---

Or you can skip the file export if you can keep the `df` in memory

```
s = pd.Series()
c = df.columns.values.tolist()
for t in df.itertuples():
    s.set_value(t.Index, str(dict(zip(c, t[1:]))))
```

Comment: But the size of data is killing the performance of the code. Would this help me overcome it? Even with a 122GB RAM on the server, my code is giving me `Coudn't reserve memory block` error.

Comment: What would be the difference between the two versions of the code?

Comment: Second is neater looking but actually slower.  I'm still trying to think of something quicker.

Comment: Oh I wouldn't bother about neat looking code. The performance is very important to me. My code absolutely comes last in that

Comment: I appreciate that... and that's why I'm still thinking about the problem.  But I'm also thinking about the many others that may search and find this question in the future.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thank you for thinking it through

Comment: @BhargaviSri still thinking if there is a quicker way... but give that last update a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144762/discussion-between-bhargavi-sri-and-pirsquared).

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [{'a':'sjdfb','b':'jsfubs'},{'a':'ouhbsdv','b':'cm osdn'}]

#convert json elements to strings and then load to df.
pd.DataFrame([str(e) for e in l])
Out[949]: 
                                  0
0     {'a': 'sjdfb', 'b': 'jsfubs'}
1  {'a': 'ouhbsdv', 'b': 'cm osdn'}
```

**Timings**

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame([str(e) for e in l])
10000 loops, best of 3: 159 µs per loop

%timeit pd.Series(df.to_dict('records'), df.index).apply(pd.json.dumps)
1000 loops, best of 3: 254 µs per loop
```

Comment: You're timing already assumes `l` has been parsed.  This isn't apples to apples.  And also notice that I included `df.index` in the `pd.Series` call.  This generalizes the process to work for any dataframe to produce a series of json strings where the index of the series is the same as the original dataframe.

Comment: Um yeah. The conversion into dictionary also is taking a lot of time on a large data. So that should be included. and when I extrapolated the time it came to around 15minutes

Comment: Oh, right, I thought your data is already in a dict format. Sorry. Will have another think.